# ssh tunnel from nagios to greenbone socket

Tags: ssh, nagios, ssh-tunnel, socket, openvas

i got 2 servers running. serverA is a monitoring solution check_mk. serverB is a vulnerability scanner with gvm20.08 (openVAS).

On my monitoring side i want to retrieve scans, tasks, targets etc. from my vulnerability scanner ,through ssh.
so i need to tunnel specific commands from serverA to gvmd-socket on serverB.

Could anyone give me a hint or some advice to get this running?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: On both machines i edited the config file:
[AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
AllowStreamLocalForwarding yes]

On my scanner machine i need to edit the ssh section "gvm-tools.conf" which requires ssh username and password. i dont know how to get these credentials. 
I dont need to create a public/private key for this scenario, do i?

This command below is actually what i need to run:
nagios-host# gvm-script --gmp-username="user name" --gmp-password="password" \
ssh --hostname 192.168.10.169 /.../libexec/check-gmp.gmp.py --ping \
GMP OK: Ping successful

Comment: or if someone could explain me how i can do it with tls instead of ssh i would appreciate lots

Comment: Cannot help you with password access. Example using keys, `command_line $USER1$/check_by_ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/var/run/nagios/$HOSTNAME$.sock -o ControlPersist=4m -i $USER2$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -l $USER3$ 'command_to_execute'`